# @username in comments; I thought they needed at least 3 letters for a match?

Tags: support, notifications, comment-replies

On one question where I commented, two people commented to @mr john afterwards, and I received two notifications. Even though my name isn't mr john.
So what's going on here? Don't at-notifications (or, comment-replies) need at least three matching letters for the person they're directed to? You may notice that in this case, only two letters match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no requirement for a minimum of 3 characters. See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

> - If the first word in the display name is at least three characters long, then there must be a starts-with, case-insensitive match of at least three characters in the display name.  This means *@a* and *@ab* will never match anyone, [unless](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61960/allow-for-comment-reply-to-usernames-with-less-than-three-characters-in-first-wor/75809#75809) a user uses a first word that is only two characters. Like: *@Jo* will notify Jo Miller, but not John, and *@B.* will notify B. Gates, but not B.Gates. If there are more than three characters in *@name*, then all given characters must match (neither *@alix* nor *@aliceinwonderland* will match user Alice).

This means you and another user got matched. Since you had done the most recent action, you received the notification.

> - Matching is performed in reverse chronological order, so if five people named John are participating, *@john* will match the most recent John. (Use the next rule to differentiate.)

Comment: Ah, because of the spaces.That clears it up. So they should just have written mrjohn.